# Why was iOS 10 password hashing switched from pbkdf2 to straight SHA-256?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, hash, ios

The subject really asks it all.

According to [this Mac Rumors article](http://www.macrumors.com/2016/09/24/itunes-backups-easier-to-crack-ios-10/), Apple changed the password hashing algorithm between iOS 9 and iOS 10 from pbkdf2 with 10,000 iterations to SHA-256 with a single pass, for phone backups to computers via iTunes.

What were they thinking? Your password keychain is among the data stored in those backups. This seems like a pretty embarrassing foible for a company so focused on security, doesn't it? Presumably they are at least appending salt to the passwords before hashing.

Comment: They probably made a lucrative behind-the-scenes deal. </tinfoil>

Comment: <tinfoil>government pressure?</tinfoil>

Comment: It seems to me that your link answers your question sufficiently when it quotes Apple's statement that they'll be fixing it in a security update.  But to paraphrase: they dun goofed.

Comment: I think it’s embarrassing for the moderators that they closed this as “primarily opinion based”.  It is widely understood in the security community that a straight unsalted hash of a password does not constitute security.